# Who should deploy a Smart Contract on to blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

If two parties were involved in the contract, should one of them deploy the smart contract onto blockchain? If yes, Who should deploy it?

For example, In Car buying process through blockchain using a smart contract between buyer and seller, who should deploy the selling Smart contract? Is it buyer or seller?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how access control are implemented in your contract. Usually, the developer deploys a smart contract through a `Truffle`. In the *migration file* set up all permissions (minter, pauser etc.) and then revoke all permissions to account from which you are deploying contracts.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter and the answer varies for different blockchains. The logic to assert that someone is the owner of a contract can be supplied in the contract or the configuration file defining policies. The important thing to consider is that the behavior of the contract should be defined before it is deployed on the blockchain.

For example: In your case, the smart contract deployer might not have any priveledges after deployment based on how your contract is designed.